# Cannot get Android Open Accessory to work on Samsung Galaxy devices

Tags: android, c, arduino, galaxy, android-open-accessory

I'm playing around with Google Open Accessory.
I've tested with a simple implementation on the Arduino Mega ADK and
an implementation on a .NET MF chip (c#).

When I connect either device to a cheap tablet, for example the ONDA V712 

(http://www.onda-sale.com/onda-v712-dual-core-7-inch-16gb.html),
the tablet detects the accessory and asks me to install the required APK.

If however I connect either device to a Samsung Galaxy S3, Note II or Note 8 it doesn't work. 
The Galaxy simply says: "Connected as USB media device".

I find it hard to believe the Galaxy range of devices are not compatible with #android open accessory so perhaps those devices need a configuration tweak of some kind? To give an idea, the code for the Arduino Mega ADK is taken from a sample from WROX:

```
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>
#include <ch9.h>
#include <Max3421e.h>
#include <Max3421e_constants.h>
#include <UsbHost.h>

char application [] = "wrox_temperature_sensor";
char accessory [] = "wrox_temperature_sensor";
char company [] = "Wiley";
char versionNbr[] = "1.0";
char serialNbr[] = "1";
char url[] = "http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/66/11184547/DOWNLOAD/t.apk";
int sensorPin = 0;
long timer = millis();
AndroidAccessory usb(company, application, accessory, versionNbr, url,serialNbr);


void setup() 
{
    usb.begin();

}

void loop() 
{
  if (usb.isConnected()) 
  {
    if( millis() - timer > 10 ) 
    {
      int val = analogRead( sensorPin );
      float voltage = (val * 5.0) / 1024.0;
      float tempCelcius = voltage * 100;
      float tempKelvin = tempCelcius + 273.15;
      byte * b = (byte *) &tempKelvin;
      usb.write(b, 4);
      timer = millis();
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm thinking the Arduino/NetMF devices are not the problem.

I've also powered the Arduino with a 12v adapter so that it has 

enough juice to power/charge the Galaxy devices.

Arduino output when connected to a Galaxy device:

> Device addressed... Requesting device descriptor. found possible
>   device. swithcing to serial mode could not read device protocol
>   version

Arduino output when connected to the Onda device:

> Device addressed... 
> Requesting device descriptor. found android
>   acessory device
>  config desc interface desc
>  1
>  2

I also checked if there is a file on each of the Galaxy devices
indicating AOA support, and there is: '*/etc/permissions/android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml*'

```
<permissions>
    <feature name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <library name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"
           file="/system/framework/com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar" />
</permissions>
```

Notes:

On the Arduino side, I'm using the `UsbHost` library from `ArduinoADK-beta-001.zip` 
which I donwloaded from the ADK site. That archive contains two versions, version 1 and version 2, but using version 2 the code and samples don't even compile.

Each of the Galaxy devices use Android 4.1.1 or higher.

Comment: Please note that I realize this question might be a bit hardware specific but I'm hoping the fact that there is enough code involved and it's development related warrants posting it here as I believe this is not something to be solved by the users of android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Support for the ADK is spotty at best. I've gotten it to work on Lenovo K1 (don't judge, we all make mistakes), Nexus 4, 7, 10, Nexus, Nexus S, and... that's it.

Comment: I figured as much. It's sad really... all I want to do is exchange data between Android and "something else" using a wired connection. Using bluetooth SPP works great, but with the lack of support for serial ports and poor ADK compatibility I'm pretty much with my back up against the wall

Comment: The most frustrating thing about this is that there's no real documentation there. You can check the IOIO project and discussion board -- they also worked out a way to transfer data over ADB. I personally got ADB working on a raspberryPi, so that might be an alternative. Seems like there was a big buzz around ADB when Google announced it, and many 3.x tablets supported it, but the whole thing quietly died in 4.1?